# BinaryFileResponse with php resource from Flysystem

Tags: php, symfony, flysystem

I need to use `BinaryFileResponse` for correct handling of videos with Length Headers and co. Also I want the user to allow configured other storages (S3, Dropbox). The flysystem `readStream` method will return a `resource` but `BinaryFileResponse` needs a `string` path. Whats the best way to handle this? First download the whole file to the server until response?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the StreamedResponse class for this. You'll have to do some data wiring yourself but it's pretty straight forward. For example, this code was used to enable "forced downloads" for PDF's.

```
return new StreamedResponse(function () use ($stream) {
    fpassthru($stream);
    exit();
}, 200, [
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
    'Content-Disposition' => sprintf('attachment; filename="%s.pdf"', $filename),
    'Content-Length' => fstat($stream)['size'],
]);
```

Comment: Think the `exit()` can be removed for compatibility with swoole, roadrunner or other long running php servers.